# Python Pandas: Iteratively extract column values from dataframe using condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, truthtable

I have two dataframes each containing 3 columns df1(A, B, C) and df2(X, Y, Z).  My aim here is extract all the rows from df1 in which the difference between A and X (A in each single row, X in all rows) is greater than a defined threshold value **and** the same for B against Y values, **and** C against Z values - then iterated for all rows in df1.  I found this rather hard to put into words so hopefully this example and truth table makes it clearer.  Example inputs (df1, df2) and output (df3).

```
thresh = 1
```

df1

```
Index  A    B    C
1      1    3    5   
2      4    2    6              
3      5    8    9
```

df2

```
Index  X    Y    Z
1      2.5  4.5  2   
2      3.5  5    6.5           
3      3.5  6    7
```

df3

```
Index  A    B    C
1      1    3    5              
3      5    8    9
```

Truth table: df1 rows should only be extracted if all tests (that is difference between A and any X, B and any Y, C and any Z) return true.

Is difference > thresh?
e.g. for df1 row 1  (**All True**, thus this df1 row is stored in df3, this would then be repeated for all other rows in df1)

```
df1[A1],df2[X1]  df1[B1],df2[Y1]  df1[C1],df2[Z1] 
True             True             True    
df1[A1],df2[X2]  df1[B1],df2[Y2]  df1[C1],df2[Z2] 
True             True             True 
df1[A1],df2[X3]  df1[B1],df2[Y3]  df1[C1],df2[Z3] 
True             True             True
```

Comment: everything seems to return True, so why not return all rows from df1

Comment: @sammywemmy I have only given a truth table for df1 row 1 (9 tests exist for each row in df1), however for df1 row 2 [A2] - [X2] = 3.5 - 4 = 0.5, which is < 1, thus at least one test has failed and row 2 should not be extracted.  I thought all three truth tables would make the question large enough to be offputting!

Answer (score 0):

With `np.repeat` and `np.tile` create your comparison tables

```
abc = np.repeat(df1.values, df2.shape[0], axis=0).reshape(df1.shape[0], -1)
xyz = np.tile(np.hstack(df2.values), df1.shape[0]).reshape(df1.shape[0], -1)

df3 = df1[np.all(np.abs(abc - xyz) > thres, axis=1)]
```

```
>>> df3
   A  B  C
1  1  3  5
3  5  8  9
```

**For testing the combinations**

```
>>> df1
    A   B   C
1  A1  B1  C1
2  A2  B2  C2
3  A3  B3  C3

>>> df2
    X   Y   Z
1  X1  Y1  Z1
2  X2  Y2  Z2
3  X3  Y3  Z3

# abc = np.repeat(df1.values, df2.shape[0], axis=0).reshape(df1.shape[0], -1)
# xyz = np.tile(np.hstack(df2.values), df1.shape[0]).reshape(df1.shape[0], -1)

>>> abc
array([['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'A1', 'B1', 'C1'],
       ['A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'A2', 'B2', 'C2'],
       ['A3', 'B3', 'C3', 'A3', 'B3', 'C3', 'A3', 'B3', 'C3']],
      dtype=object)

>>> xyz
array([['X1', 'Y1', 'Z1', 'X2', 'Y2', 'Z2', 'X3', 'Y3', 'Z3'],
       ['X1', 'Y1', 'Z1', 'X2', 'Y2', 'Z2', 'X3', 'Y3', 'Z3'],
       ['X1', 'Y1', 'Z1', 'X2', 'Y2', 'Z2', 'X3', 'Y3', 'Z3']],
      dtype=object)
```

Comment: @SasCom, please can you take time to check the solution please...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to put this as a comment or an answer, because this is a question where clarifying exactly what you mean and answering the question are close to the same thing.

If I understand what you want correctly, I think this will do it:

```
def check_row(row):
    return all(
                any(
                    abs(row[col1]-n2)> threshold
                    for n2 in df2[col2]
                    )
                for col1, col2 in 
                    zip(df1.columns, df2.columns)
        )

df1.loc[df1.apply(check_row, axis = 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.  Unfortunately I haven't been able to get this code to work, KeyError 'A' is returned when applying to df1.loc[df2.apply(check_row, axis = 1)]  - forgive me if I am missing something obvious here.

Comment: @SasCom Try `df1.loc[df1.apply(check_row, axis = 1)]` I originally had `df` instead of `df1`, which may have confused you into thinking that you should plug in the different dataframe names. It's `df1` for both `df1.loc` and `df1.apply`; `check_row` is taking `df2` as a global variable rather than an argument.